# How to customize product search service in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to customize product search in hybris and return only products which are only having stocks. But i cannot find the query. Can anyone advise me from where should i start?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways which is coming in my mind

1. You can change full/update index query which will return only those products which have stocks. Solr will index only those products.
2. Let index all the products. You need to create one custom provider that will index stock per every product. Then you can apply filter to get only those products which have stock.

Comment: Is there any reference for "create one custom provider"?

Comment: Also if you want, you can get all products and filter them in the controller, but getting directly those from SOLR may be a better solution. It depends on exactly what do you want.